# What am I doing wrong with the routes in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, routes

I have the problem that the routes are not taken over. Menu item 1 always accesses customers when editing etc. although it should read announcements.

I have 2 menu items customers and announcements both I can call. However, when I go to edit announcements in the index, the route points to customers.

it says instead of announcements/create then customers/create there

`

```
$router->group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    
    // Announcements
    Route::get('announcements', [App\Http\Controllers\AnnouncementsController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
    Route::post('announcements', [App\Http\Controllers\AnnouncementsController::class, 'store'])->name('store');
    Route::get('announcements/create', [App\Http\Controllers\AnnouncementsController::class, 'create'])->name('create');
    Route::get('announcements/{announcements}', [App\Http\Controllers\AnnouncementsController::class, 'show'])->name('show');
    Route::put('announcements/{announcements}', [App\Http\Controllers\AnnouncementsController::class, 'update'])->name('update');
    Route::delete('announcements/{announcements}', [App\Http\Controllers\AnnouncementsController::class, 'destroy'])->name('destroy');
    Route::get('announcements/{announcements}/edit', [App\Http\Controllers\AnnouncementsController::class, 'edit'])->name('edit');
    
    // Customers
    Route::get('customers', [App\Http\Controllers\CustomersController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
    Route::post('customers', [App\Http\Controllers\CustomersController::class, 'store'])->name('store');
    Route::get('customers/create', [App\Http\Controllers\CustomersController::class, 'create'])->name('create');
    Route::get('customers/{customers}', [App\Http\Controllers\CustomersController::class, 'show'])->name('show');
    Route::put('customers/{customers}', [App\Http\Controllers\CustomersController::class, 'update'])->name('update');
    Route::delete('customers/{customers}', [App\Http\Controllers\CustomersController::class, 'destroy'])->name('destroy');
    Route::get('customers/{customers}/edit', [App\Http\Controllers\CustomersController::class, 'edit'])->name('edit');

});
```

`

`

```
$router->group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    
    // Announcements
    Route::get('announcements', [App\Http\Controllers\AnnouncementsController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
    Route::post('announcements', [App\Http\Controllers\AnnouncementsController::class, 'store'])->name('store');
    Route::get('announcements/create', [App\Http\Controllers\AnnouncementsController::class, 'create'])->name('create');
    Route::get('announcements/{announcements}', [App\Http\Controllers\AnnouncementsController::class, 'show'])->name('show');
    Route::put('announcements/{announcements}', [App\Http\Controllers\AnnouncementsController::class, 'update'])->name('update');
    Route::delete('announcements/{announcements}', [App\Http\Controllers\AnnouncementsController::class, 'destroy'])->name('destroy');
    Route::get('announcements/{announcements}/edit', [App\Http\Controllers\AnnouncementsController::class, 'edit'])->name('edit');
    
    // Customers
    Route::get('customers', [App\Http\Controllers\CustomersController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
    Route::post('customers', [App\Http\Controllers\CustomersController::class, 'store'])->name('store');
    Route::get('customers/create', [App\Http\Controllers\CustomersController::class, 'create'])->name('create');
    Route::get('customers/{customers}', [App\Http\Controllers\CustomersController::class, 'show'])->name('show');
    Route::put('customers/{customers}', [App\Http\Controllers\CustomersController::class, 'update'])->name('update');
    Route::delete('customers/{customers}', [App\Http\Controllers\CustomersController::class, 'destroy'])->name('destroy');
    Route::get('customers/{customers}/edit', [App\Http\Controllers\CustomersController::class, 'edit'])->name('edit');

});
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You have to give named routes *different* names, like `announcements.index` and `companies.index`.

Comment: You mean like this?


Route::get('announcements', [AnnouncementsController::class, 'index'])->name('announcements.index');

Comment: Yes. You can use anything - `announcementsIndex`, `announcements_index`, `a.index`, `stupidRouteFinallyWorksNow`, etc., as long as it's unique; no other route can have the same name. Otherwise, Laravel has no idea which one you mean when you do `redirect()->route('index')`.

Comment: Danke dir, hat funktioniert.